# Notepad++ regex to find lines with more than n pipe-characters

Tags: regex, csv, character, notepad++

once again I have a problem with a regex in Notepad++, since I don't know a lot about it.
I have a .csv file, but I need to find all lines with n (let's say 4) or more pipe-characters.
Example of the string I have:

```
6454345|User1-2ds3|62562012032|9c1fe63ccd3ab234892beaf71f022be2e06b6cd1
3305611|User2-42g563dgsdbf|22023001345|c36dedfa12634e33ca8bc0ef4703c92b73d9c433
8749412|User3-9|xgs|f|98906504456|411b0fdf54fe29745897288c6ad699f7be30f389
5151540|User4-jy|n|12202310|6a54c608289f4aedfab63ca640bcd5d174fd8592
```

I need to find these strings, they have 4 or more pipe-characters:

```
8749412|User3-9|xgs|f|98906504456|411b0fdf54fe29745897288c6ad699f7be30f389 
5151540|User4-jy|n|12202310|6a54c608289f4aedfab63ca640bcd5d174fd8592
```

I did some searches here but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for, so far I used the answers provided in these questions, besides that I didn't find anything similar:
[Find Lines with N occurrences of a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068964/find-lines-with-n-occurrences-of-a-char)
[Regular expression to match text that contains n or more of specified character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464461/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-contains-n-or-more-of-specified-character)
I replaced the requested characters in a pipe-character, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you just use `|` or `\|`? Please post what you tried. Also, what do you need to do with the lines? Just find? Or replace/modify in any way?

Comment: I just need to find these lines and will fix them manually since they all need a different treatment.
This is what I've tried for example:
^[^|\\r\n]*(?:\|[^|\\r\n]*){4,}$ or this: (.*?\|){4,} and this: ^(|\[^|\]*){4,}

Comment: Just to ([|][^|\n]*){4,}.*

Answer (score 1):

You may use either of the two expressions below to match line that have 4 pipes:

```
^(.*?\|){4}
```

or

```
^([^|\r\n]*\|){4}
```

Note that you need to have *`.` matches newline* option OFF to make the first pattern work.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `(.*?\|){4}` - 4 occurrences of any chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first `|` and then a `|` char
- `[^|\r\n]` - matches any char but a `|`, CR and LF symbols.

[image]

Comment: Tried it, seems like that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dyon: Just note that to use a literal `|` in the regex, you need to escape it, or put inside `[...]`, a character class. When inside a character class, many chars lose their special meaning: `[(){+$]` matches a single char that is either a literal `(`, `)`, `{`, `+`, `$` symbols.